# Vim syntax files: add to cterm

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Consider a simple text markup language where `_underscores denote italics_` and `*astrisks denote bold*`.

In an imaginary vim syntax file you might have

```
syntax region italic start='_' end='_' keepend
syntax region bold start='*' end='*' keepend
highlight italic cterm=italic
highlight bold cterm=bold
```

(yes I know that it's `\*`, I left it as `*` for clarity.)

The problem here is `_strings like *this*_`. Even if your terminal supports italicBold fonts you only get one at a time in vim.

What I really want to do is this:

```
highlight italic cterm+=italic
highlight bold cterm+=bold
```

(`term` and `guiterm` omitted for clarity.)

It's possible to work around this with contained `italicBold` and `boldItalic` regions that both set `cterm=bold,italic`, but things get messy when you want to include `underline` and everything gets out of hand *entirely* when you have a red region and a blue region and you wind up with

```
syntax region red ... contains=italicRed,boldRed,underlineRed
syntax region italicRed ... contains=italicBoldRed,italicUnderlineRed
syntax region italicBoldRed ... contains=italicBoldUnderlineRed
.
.
.

highlight red ctermfg=red
highlight italicRed cterm=italic ctermfg=red
highlight italicBoldRed cterm=italic,bold ctermfg=red
.
.
.
```

ad inifinitum.

And the kicker is that really I don't want to hard code the color to `red`. I'd prefer to

```
highlight link red Statement
```

and then have `italicRed` use the same highlight definition as `red` but *add* the italic setting.

There's *got* to be an easier way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15974676/1290438) offers some kind of workaround that may be interesting to get from here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All syntax plugins that I have seen so far use the workaround you describe.

Why doesn't offer Vim something better? (I had once also wished for the possibility to overlay colors, i.e. when a light yellow background is on top of light gray, it becomes dark yellow.) With high- and low-color terminals and the GUI, this is difficult to implement (anyone like a challenge?), and syntax highlighting is first and foremost for a few common programming constructs (comments, statements, identifiers, etc.), not the elaborate markup you have in mind.