# Superpose two vim syntax matches on the same character

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm defining the following syntax rules in a vimscript:

```
hi MyBold term=bold   gui=bold
hi MyRed  ctermfg=red guifg=#ff0000
```

And later on, I want to apply both highlights to the same character. So basically, I tried the following:

```
syn match MyRed  /\%1c\%1l./
syn match MyBold /\%1c\%1l./
```

but then the second match replaces the first match. So, I further read the help on `syntax match`, and also the answer to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819006/vim-syntax-files-trying-to-undestand-contains) and I tried playing with the `syn match` parameters:

```
syn match MyRed  /\%1c\%1l./ contains=CONTAINED
syn match MyBold /\%1c\%1l./ contained
```

but it still behaves the exact same way.

So, how could I use two syntax matches to change independently the background and the foreground of the same character?

Comment: I agree it is a duplicate to that one, though I have looked up on stackoverflow for similar answers, and I did not see that one.

Comment: Upvoted because of your demo at TupperVim. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. For each character, Vim only uses one particular highlight group, determined by the last, "most inner" non-transparent syntax group match.

To work around this, define a combined highlight group and corresponding `:syntax` commands.

```
:hi MyBoldRed cterm=bold ctermfg=red gui=bold guifg=#ff0000
```

Some syntaxes (e.g. `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`, and various Wiki formats) use that for combining bold, italic and underline, but it gets tedious and repetitive after that. But remember that Vim is not meant for WYSIWYG; syntax highlighting just provides some hints.

**Edit**: There's a [patch proposed](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/e58820848647ffec/0bb8fefb0d2133ea#0bb8fefb0d2133ea) that would add a `combine` modifier for `:syntax` commands; it's in Bram's Todo list.

Comment: Of course, I know that vim is not meant to be WYSIWYG, but I'm writing a [plugin](https://github.com/guyzmo/vim-etherpad) that connects a vim buffer to etherpad-lite, and I'd like to make the plugin support text attributes as well as author colorization.

Comment: But I find it quite weird that it is not possible to make two syntax highlightings overlap, whereas it is possible using `:match` and `:2match`…

Comment: It's a limitation; I've found a patch that proposes to allow this; see my edit.

Comment: oh that would definitively rock! I'll work around that in my current code, and make it in my README.md that I can't wait for Bram to integrate that patch :-D